# How to save big array of objects in react native using react-native-db-model

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reactjs-flux

```
storage.people.add_all(people_array, function(people_array){
  console.log("people_array",people_array)
});
```

people_array is about 1000 records and limit can exceed in future.

This method is taking more than 5 minutes to save into the db so performance is too slow.Can anybody suggest me how to proceed with db structure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @FuzzyTree are you pointing to change people array as big that i have changed. is it fine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you will need to insert all the records in one object rather inserting them row by row. If you want to do that you will have to insert between installation procedure. But will recommend to insert one monolithic object one time like below.

```
storage.people.add(people_array, function(people_array){
 console.log("people_array",people_array)
});
```

This should reduce huge time on saving records.